# Upstairs load question

Tags: framing

The home in question is in Orange County California. I believe most upstairs floor joist are 2"x10" 16" on center. What is the pounds per square feet.

If my box foot print 60"x80"and weighs 2000lbs would it be safe at 30psf

Comment: that box is  60PSF

Comment: the strength of the floor also depends on how far the joists span

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please only post your question once; add detail to the original if you need  to.

Comment: Can a safe rated at 60 PSF sit on an upstairs floor that is rated at 30 PSF?